# Twilio Outgoing call via batchfile

Tags: batch-file, twilio, phone-call

I would like to make outgoing calls via .bat file, so another program can just execute the batch file and there will be an outgoing call.

I've searched and I found this website: 
https://www.twilio.com/labs/bash

They explain how to make an outgoing call via .bat file, but it's not clear for me what to do with it.

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

As far as I know there is not native way to make HTTP requests from a batch file in Windows, so you'll need to use a command line executable like wget or curl.

You can find an [example of the curl command](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#example-1) in our docs (select the JSON option)

Another option would be to use Powershell.  You can find a nice [Twilio powershell library on github](https://github.com/jodoglevy/TwilioPowerShell).

Hope that helps.